# Is there a way to shell out to a different program and let it take over?

Tags: node.js

I have a program that takes a cluster name, does some lookups, figures out what's missing, and produces an SSH invocation that will get you a prompt on a given box.

I'd like to actually **run** the program (meaning you're dropped at the relevant bash prompt) instead of just telling the user to run the blurb themselves, but I can't seem to find a way to do so with node, [mostly out of concern for Windows or worker threads](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21664). (Non-interactive SSH sessions are basically not a thing in our environment.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is close enough for my needs, although I'm sure it will be somehow subtly wrong around signals or whatnot:

```js
import {spawn} from 'child_process';
spawn('ssh',
  ['-o', 'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', ...],
  {
    detached: false,
    stdio: 'inherit',
  }
);
```

Execution will block at the `spawn()` call, meaning your process will continue running, and any monitoring on runtime of your commands will have a bad time... but oh well.